# How to insert 11 blank rows after each unique value

Tags: excel, vba

I have created code for 1 blank row but I need to change it to 11 blank rows
 I have 4000 values in A row. i need to insert 11 rows after each unique value found in A row

```
Sub AddBlankRows()
'
Dim iRow As Integer, iCol As Integer
Dim oRng As Range

Set oRng = Range("a1")

iRow = oRng.Row
iCol = oRng.Column

Do
'
If Cells(iRow + 1, iCol) <> Cells(iRow, iCol) Then
    Cells(iRow + 11, iCol).EntireRow.Insert shift:=x1Down
    iRow = iRow + 2
Else
    iRow = iRow + 1

End If
'
Loop While Not Cells(iRow, iCol).Text = ""
'
End Sub
```

So this code is inserting 1 blank row after each unique value.
I would like to change it to 11 blank rows.

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: You should work from the bottom up, not from top down. This is because row numbers change when you start inserting rows. You want these changes in a part of the sheet which your code will not refer to again. Therefore iRow = iRow -1 (having started at the bottom).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert Specific Number of Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43525799/insert-specific-number-of-rows)

Comment: No @braX i need to run the same until blank cell found

Comment: So the real question is then "how do I increment until the blank cell is found "?

Comment: How many rows of values do you have in your starting column? It could be done without iteration at all.

Comment: @JvdV i have 4000 values in row A. i need 11 rows between each row value

Comment: Change oRange with offset 11 and get irow again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scratch my last answer, as per your last comments (and screenshots):

> *"I have 4000 values in row A. i need 11 rows between each row value"*

And:

> *"In my data value present in A row will be unique (i.e) Range A:A 4000 rows are unique"*

This, to me, reads like all your values are unique. No need to test anything nomore then:

```
Sub Test()

Dim lr As Long, x As Long, ws As Worksheet

'Set your worksheet as variable
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

'Get last used row of column A and fill array
lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'Loop backwards
For x = lr + 1 To 3 Step -1
    ws.Rows(x).Resize(11).Insert xlShiftDown
Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: it is inserting only 11 cells not 11 rows. Also it doesn't continue the loop. It inserts 11 cells after A2 and it stops

Comment: added before and after screenshot of my sample data. i need 11 rows between each cells. please help me out to get it finished

Comment: @JvdV in my data value present in A row will be unique (i.e) Range A:A 4000 rows are unique

Comment: @JvdV the last one is working fine.. thanks for the timely response

Comment: No worries @Roguen. Glad it's sorted. Please clean up the redundant comments =)